# Footer image not on the same Line with Footer Text

Tags: css, reactjs

I want the image / logo on the footer to be on the same line as the text on the footer, but whatever I do,it goes below the Line and looks like this

[image: 231.png]

My css code is looking like this

```
.header{
    background-color: #007FC0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 0;
}

.container{
    flex : 1 1 auto;
    color:white;
}

.needhelpText{
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
}

.copyrightText{
    margin: 8px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.footerLinks{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.footerLogo{
    float: right;
    width : 134px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #16192C;
}
```

My React Code looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import './app-styles.css';
import Vector from './Vector.png'
import ie_logo from './ie_logo.png';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <header className="header">
        <img src={Vector} style={{margin:7, flexDirection:'column', alignItems: 'center'}} alt="Vector" />
        <img src={ie_logo} style={{margin:7, flexDirection: 'row', width:114, height:25}} alt="ie_logo" />
        <p className="needhelpText">LOGIN HERE?</p>
        </header>
            <form>
                <label>
                    Hello React Label
                </label>
            </form>
        <footer className="footer">
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks"> Privacy Policy | &nbsp; </a>
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks">Do Not Sell My Personal Information | &nbsp; </a>
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks">Advertising Guidelines | &nbsp;</a>   
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks">Site Map  &nbsp;</a>  

        <div className="copyrightText">
        © Copyright 2021 | Luther Corp | All Rights Reserved
        </div>
        <img src={ie_logo} style={{margin:9}} className="footerLogo" alt="ie_logo" />
        </footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

The Css holding this is the footer Logo which is this one

```
.footerLogo{
    float: right;
    width : 134px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Pls what am I missing? Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out giving your footer a 100% width attribute? And if so, please also check the width of the logo. Incase that doesn't work out you can always create a div with 100% width containing only the logo. Than give that dive a text-align:right; attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what's going on without a logo, but I think the footerLogo css height and inline-block are clashing.

If you want to have all the child elements in the same line whilst keeping their height the same (and therefore centered), use a display: flex on the parent without flex wrap. You can then use css margin-left: auto on the logo to make it float to the right and whatever height you want.

PS: align-items property does not work unless the container is display:flex. And it's confusing to add style when there's a class (unless the style is dynamically determined).